# (python) Не удается создать спот ордер через api binance

Tags: python, api, бот, binance

Баланс есть, ошибок в логах нет. Как только rsi превышает порог ордер не создается, и вообще ничего не происходит

```
import csv
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import Fore
from telegram import Bot
import ccxt
import numpy as np
import talib

from config import api_key, api_secret, api_tg, tg_id


class ShortingBot:
    def __init__(self, exchange, symbols, api_key, api_secret, max_order_volume, stop_loss=0.02, take_profit=0.04,
                 trailing_stop_atr=None, order_check_interval=300, rsi_period=14, rsi_oversold=35, rsi_overbought=65):
        self.exchange = exchange
        self.symbols = symbols
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.max_order_volume = max_order_volume
        self.stop_loss = stop_loss
        self.take_profit = take_profit
        self.trailing_stop_atr = trailing_stop_atr
        self.order_check_interval = order_check_interval
        self.rsi_period = rsi_period
        self.rsi_oversold = rsi_oversold
        self.rsi_overbought = rsi_overbought

        self.open_positions = {}
        self.telegram_bot_token = api_tg
        self.telegram_chat_id = tg_id
        self.telegram_bot = Bot(token=self.telegram_bot_token)

        self.log_filename = 'shorting_bot.log'
        self.csv_filename = 'trading_stats.csv'
        self.create_log_file()
        self.create_trade_history_file()

    async def send_telegram_message(self, message):
        try:
            await self.telegram_bot.send_message(chat_id=self.telegram_chat_id, text=message)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Ошибка при отправке сообщения в Телеграм: {str(e)}")

    async def initialize_exchange(self):
        try:

            self.exchange = ccxt.binance({
                'apiKey': self.api_key,
                'secret': self.api_secret,
            })
            print(f"[{Fore.GREEN}API{Fore.RESET}] Бот успешно подключился к API Binance")
            await self.send_telegram_message("[API] Бот успешно подключился к API Binance")

            for symbol in self.symbols:
                self.print_symbol_balance(symbol)

        except ccxt.NetworkError as e:
            logging.error(f"[{Fore.RED}API{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка сети при подключении к API Binance: {str(e)}")
            await self.send_telegram_message(f"[API] Ошибка сети при подключении к API Binance: {str(e)}")
        except ccxt.ExchangeError as e:
            logging.error(f"[{Fore.RED}API{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка биржи при подключении к API Binance: {str(e)}")
            await self.send_telegram_message(f"[API] Ошибка биржи при подключении к API Binance: {str(e)}")

    def create_log_file(self):
        logging.basicConfig(filename=self.log_filename, level=logging.INFO,
                            format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                            filemode='w', encoding='utf-8')
        header = ['Timestamp', 'Symbol', 'Price', 'RSI', 'Action']
        with open(self.csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)

    @staticmethod
    def create_trade_history_file():
        header = ['Timestamp', 'Symbol', 'Entry Price', 'Exit Price', 'Profit (%)']
        with open('trade_history.csv', mode='w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)

    def print_symbol_balance(self, symbol):
        try:
            balance = self.exchange.fetch_balance()
            if symbol in balance['total']:
                print(f"[{Fore.CYAN}Баланс{Fore.RESET}] {symbol}: {balance['total'][symbol]:.8f}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Ошибка при получении баланса для {symbol}: {str(e)}")

    def monitor_market(self):
        while True:
            try:
                for symbol in self.symbols:
                    self.check_open_orders()
                    ticker = self.exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
                    last_price = ticker['last']
                    rsi_data = self.fetch_rsi(symbol)
                    if rsi_data is not None:
                        new_rsi = rsi_data['RSI']
                        self.record_stat(datetime.now(), symbol, last_price, new_rsi)
                        self.print_symbol_balance(symbol)
                        if new_rsi >= self.rsi_overbought and symbol not in self.open_positions:
                            if not self.has_open_orders(symbol):
                                if self.has_sufficient_balance(symbol, last_price):
                                    self.short(symbol, last_price)
                                    logging.info(f"[SHORT] Создан ордер на шорт для {symbol}")
                        elif new_rsi <= self.rsi_oversold and symbol in self.open_positions:
                            self.cover(symbol, last_price)
                            logging.info(f"[COVER] Позиция закрыта для {symbol}")
                    self.trailing_stop()
                    time.sleep(1)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Произошла ошибка: {str(e)}")

    def has_open_orders(self, symbol):
        try:
            orders = self.exchange.fetch_open_orders(symbol)
            return len(orders) > 0
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Ошибка при проверке открытых ордеров: {str(e)}")
            return True

    def has_sufficient_balance(self, symbol, price):
        try:
            balance = self.exchange.fetch_balance()
            quote_currency = symbol.split('/')[1]
            if symbol in balance['total'] and quote_currency in balance['total']:
                order_volume = min(self.max_order_volume.get(symbol), self.max_order_volume.get(symbol) / price)
                needed_quote_amount = order_volume * price
                quote_balance = balance['total'][quote_currency]
                return needed_quote_amount <= quote_balance
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Ошибка при проверке баланса: {str(e)}")
            return False

    def short(self, symbol, price):
        try:

            if self.max_order_volume.get(symbol) is not None:
                order_volume = min(self.max_order_volume.get(symbol), self.max_order_volume.get(symbol) / price)
            else:
                order_volume = None
            if order_volume > 0:
                print(f"[{Fore.RED}Шорт{Fore.RESET}] {symbol} по цене {price}")

                while True:
                    try:

                        order = self.exchange.create_limit_sell_order(
                            symbol,
                            order_volume,
                            price
                        )
                        if 'id' in order:

                            self.open_positions[symbol] = {
                                'entry_price': price,
                                'stop_loss_price': price * (1 + self.stop_loss),
                                'take_profit_price': price * (1 - self.take_profit),
                                'order_id': order['id'],
                                'order_volume': order_volume
                            }
                            logging.info(f"[{Fore.RED}Шорт{Fore.RESET}] {symbol} по цене {price}")
                            break
                        else:
                            logging.error(f"[{Fore.RED}Шорт{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка при открытии шорт-позиции: {order}")

                            time.sleep(5)
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"[{Fore.RED}Шорт{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка при открытии шорт-позиции: {str(e)}")

                        time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"[{Fore.RED}Шорт{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка при открытии шорт-позиции: {str(e)}")

    def cover(self, symbol, price):
        try:
            if symbol in self.open_positions:
                print(f"[{Fore.GREEN}Покрытие{Fore.RESET}] {symbol} по цене {price}")

                while True:
                    try:

                        self.exchange.create_limit_buy_order(
                            symbol,
                            self.open_positions[symbol]['entry_price'],
                            self.open_positions[symbol]['order_volume']
                        )
                        profit = (price / self.open_positions[symbol]['entry_price'] - 1) * 100

                        self.record_trade_history(datetime.now(), symbol, self.open_positions[symbol]['entry_price'],
                                                  price, profit)
                        del self.open_positions[symbol]
                        logging.info(
                            f"[{Fore.GREEN}Покрытие{Fore.RESET}] {symbol} по цене {price}, прибыль {profit:.2f}%")
                        break
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"[{Fore.GREEN}Покрытие{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка при покрытии шорт-позиции: {str(e)}")

                        time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"[{Fore.GREEN}Покрытие{Fore.RESET}] Ошибка при покрытии шорт-позиции: {str(e)}")

    def fetch_rsi(self, symbol):
        try:
            rsi_data = self.exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe='15m', limit=self.rsi_period + 1)
            if len(rsi_data) >= self.rsi_period + 1:
                closes = np.array([candle[4] for candle in rsi_data], dtype=float)
                rsi_values = talib.RSI(closes, self.rsi_period)
                return {'RSI': rsi_values[-1]}
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Ошибка при получении RSI для {symbol}: {str(e)}")
            return None

    def record_stat(self, timestamp, symbol, price, rsi):
        row = [timestamp, symbol, price, rsi, '']
        with open(self.csv_filename, mode='a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)

    @staticmethod
    def record_trade_history(timestamp, symbol, entry_price, exit_price, profit):
        row = [timestamp, symbol, entry_price, exit_price, profit]
        with open('trade_history.csv', mode='a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)

    def check_open_orders(self):
        for symbol, order in self.open_positions.items():
            try:
                status = self.exchange.fetch_order_status(order['order_id'])
                if status['status'] == 'closed':
                    del self.open_positions[symbol]
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Ошибка проверки ордера {order['order_id']}: {e}")

    def trailing_stop(self):
        for symbol, order in self.open_positions.items():
            try:
                ticker = self.exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
                current_price = ticker['last']
                if current_price > order['entry_price'] * (1 + self.trailing_stop_atr):
                    order['stop_loss_price'] = current_price * (1 - self.stop_loss)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Ошибка при обновлении стоп-лосса для {symbol}: {e}")

    async def run(self):
        await self.initialize_exchange()
        self.monitor_market()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exchange = 'binance'
    symbols = ['BCH/USDT', 'ETH/USDT', 'SOL/USDT']
    max_order_volume = {
        'BCH/USDT': 0.025,
        'ETH/USDT': 0.0051,
        'SOL/USDT': 0.04
    }
    stop_loss = 0.02
    take_profit = 0.04
    rsi_period = 14
    rsi_oversold = 35
    rsi_overbought = 65

    bot = ShortingBot(exchange, symbols, api_key, api_secret, max_order_volume, stop_loss, take_profit,
                      rsi_period=rsi_period, rsi_oversold=rsi_oversold, rsi_overbought=rsi_overbought)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(bot.run())
```

Comment: Есть какой то лог от коннектора бинанса или коннектора? Обычно там показывается причина ошибки (я так понимаю, она явно на этапе выставления ордера - т.е. на обращении к бирже)

Comment: Судя по всему мой код не отлавливает ошибки от binance, и поэтому в логах ничего по этому поводу нет

Comment: вы проверяли, у вас работают запросы к бирже через ccxt вообще?